# MongoDB php subquery

Tags: mongodb, subquery

i'm new to nosql and currently trying to work with mongodb.

From sql statement:

```
select id from table1 where id in (select related_id from table2 where column_name='somevalue')
```

what would be the equivalent mongodb/php syntax of this query ?

I have populated the 2 collections with sample data, trying to figure out with aggregate but no results so far. There are plenty of samples around but couldn't find something of this type of sub-query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## get the ids from table2

```
ids = db.table2.find({ "columnname": "somevalue"},{ id: 1, _id: 0 })
```

## query the table1 collection with the ids from previous query

```
db.table1.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids } },{id:1,_id:0})
```

Comment: thnx for the suggestion but for large data this is heavy passing ids through arrays all the time.